# How to sort same next value in foreach loop using php?

Tags: php

I new to PHP. What I want to do is hide the same data in a foreach loop.

**Here is my code:**

```
foreach($recording_record as $row ){
echo $row->criteria_title;
echo $row->question_title;
}
```

**My current interface:**[image]

**How I want my interface to be:**

[image]

Here is my print_r data:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [record_id] => 6 [qm_id] => 2 [qm_title] => QM LEAD 2 [record_filename] => abcdefgh.mp3 [userid] => 1002 [unique_id] => 1325554791.71044 [supervisor_id] => 1000 [date_created] => 2013-05-14 05:29:24 [status] => 3 [id] => 6 [callid] => 1325554791.71044 [callerid] => 0383153394 [queuename] => t1-BM_OE [extension] => SIP/1003 [ivrtime] => 2013-05-14 11:14:36 [queuetime] => 2012-01-03 09:40:33 [connecttime] => 2013-05-09 09:40:36 [disconnecttime] => 2012-01-03 09:46:34 [callduration] => 358 [holdduration] => 0 [queueduration] => 3 [ansduration] => 3 [ringduration] => 0 [lastevent] => COMPLETEAGENT [transfer] => [wrapups] => ,12 [tenantid] => 1 [supervisor] => 1005 [username] => Fara [userpass] => 1234 [lastname] => Binti Johari [firstname] => Nurul Farahhin [userlevel] => 2 [usercreated] => 2011-03-26 23:11:56 [lastlogin] => 2012-10-13 20:17:10 [userexten] => [sessionid] => [userstatusid] => 0 [apptype] => webagent [statustimestamp] => 2012-10-13 20:33:21 [lastuserstatusid] => 1 [pqueuetimeout] => 0 [queueroutetype] => 1 [queueroutevalue] => 4 [userdbstatus] => A [criteria_id] => 1 [criteria_title] => Did not demonstrate inappropriate behavior - Zero Tolerance Policy [criteria_rate] => 40 [question_id] => 4 [question_title] => Question 2 [question_type] => n [question_score_y_yes] => [question_score_y_no] => [question_score_y_answer] => [question_score_y] => [question_score_n_a] => 1 [question_score_n_a_value] => True [question_score_n_b] => 0 [question_score_n_b_value] => False [question_score_n_c] => 0 [question_score_n_c_value] => [question_score_n_d] => 0 [question_score_n_d_value] => [question_score_n_e] => 0 [question_score_n_e_value] => [question_score_n_answer] => [question_score_n] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [record_id] => 6 [qm_id] => 2 [qm_title] => QM LEAD 2 [record_filename] => abcdefgh.mp3 [userid] => 1002 [unique_id] => 1325554791.71044 [supervisor_id] => 1000 [date_created] => 2013-05-14 05:29:24 [status] => 3 [id] => 6 [callid] => 1325554791.71044 [callerid] => 0383153394 [queuename] => t1-BM_OE [extension] => SIP/1003 [ivrtime] => 2013-05-14 11:14:36 [queuetime] => 2012-01-03 09:40:33 [connecttime] => 2013-05-09 09:40:36 [disconnecttime] => 2012-01-03 09:46:34 [callduration] => 358 [holdduration] => 0 [queueduration] => 3 [ansduration] => 3 [ringduration] => 0 [lastevent] => COMPLETEAGENT [transfer] => [wrapups] => ,12 [tenantid] => 1 [supervisor] => 1005 [username] => Fara [userpass] => 1234 [lastname] => Binti Johari [firstname] => Nurul Farahhin [userlevel] => 2 [usercreated] => 2011-03-26 23:11:56 [lastlogin] => 2012-10-13 20:17:10 [userexten] => [sessionid] => [userstatusid] => 0 [apptype] => webagent [statustimestamp] => 2012-10-13 20:33:21 [lastuserstatusid] => 1 [pqueuetimeout] => 0 [queueroutetype] => 1 [queueroutevalue] => 4 [userdbstatus] => A [criteria_id] => 1 [criteria_title] => Did not demonstrate inappropriate behavior - Zero Tolerance Policy [criteria_rate] => 40 [question_id] => 3 [question_title] => Question 1 [question_type] => y [question_score_y_yes] => 1 [question_score_y_no] => 0 [question_score_y_answer] => [question_score_y] => [question_score_n_a] => [question_score_n_a_value] => [question_score_n_b] => [question_score_n_b_value] => [question_score_n_c] => [question_score_n_c_value] => [question_score_n_d] => [question_score_n_d_value] => [question_score_n_e] => [question_score_n_e_value] => [question_score_n_answer] => [question_score_n] => )
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What's the structure of your data? I.E. What is inside `$row`?

Comment: this is my $row example stdClass Object ( [record_id] => 6 [qm_id] => 2 [qm_title] => QM LEAD 2 [record_filename] => abcdefgh.mp3 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$criteria = array();
foreach($recording_record as $row ){

  $criteria[$i] = $row->criteria_title;
  if($i > 0){
      if ($criteria[$i] != $criteria[$i-1]){
         echo $criteria[$i];
       }
   } else {
        echo $criteria[$i];
   }

  echo $row->question_title;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie, it's almost there, but the problem I got multiple of different criteria_title also, I just want to sort if got same criteria_title in the loop, isn't possible?

Comment: Answer is Updated :); Let me know what happen.

Comment: after i added your code, now my interface become blank with no error, do you know what happen ?

Comment: I had updated my print_r data from $recording_record, have a look

Comment: Try my answer again please :)

Comment: thanks, sorry late reply, you save my life man. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $new_recording_record = array_unique($recording_record);
```

Comment: hi Sudz, can provide full code for me ? I am using codeigniter now, so  I do not know how to put your code in my code , thanks :)

Comment: You can use it directly in CodeIgniter. Instead of $recording_record in foreach loop use $new_recording_record variable.

Comment: It's work, but the I got a lot of question, now only show one question instead of a lot question

Comment: What do you mean 'one question'? Be specific what do you want?

Comment: Actually I got a lot of different criteria_title, each criteria_title got more than 1 question_title, after I used your code, my 1 criteria_title only show 1 question instead of show more than 1 question

Comment: Post your code.
What your $recording_record is returning and what output do you want?

Comment: I had updated my print_r data from $recording_record, have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works?

```
$i = 1;
foreach($recording_record as $row ){
    $title = $row->criteria_title;
    $question_title = $row->question_title;

    if($ငငငi==1)
       echo $title;

    echo $question_title;  

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo $recording_record[0]->criteria_title;
foreach($recording_record as $row ){

echo $row->question_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks abdul quadir, it's work, but the problem I got multiple of different criteria_title also, i just want to sort if got same criteria_title